# Glide does not cache images locally

Tags: android, android-glide

I have the following code :

```
   @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder h, int position) {
        Product product = productArrayList.get(position);
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)h;


        final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;
        FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("images/"+product.imageName).getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                product.setBitmap(bitmap);
                Glide.with(context).load(product.getBitmap()).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).into(holder.productImageView);
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) { }
        });

}
```

and it doesn't cache the images. It just reloads it every time I re-run the app. The image should be loaded instantly for the succeeding runs after the first one, but no, it just doesn't cache the images.

Answer (score -1):

In this case, you are referencing the Bitmap of your Product object, and so Glide has no way of knowing that you're loading the same image every time. In scenarios like this, Glide can use [cache keys](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html#cache-keys) to recognize when it is appropriate to load from the cache. For example, if you were loading from a URL (e.g., as a String) instead of a Bitmap and the URL were the same every time, then the image would be loaded from the cache because the URL would have a consistent value for hashCode() and equals(). In your case, it might be better to identify a unique property of the Product object and use it as the [ObjectKey](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html#custom-cache-invalidation) to provide a customer signature when loading. So, let's say your Product has an `id` that can be referenced with `getId()`. Then...

```java
Glide.with(fragment)
  .load(product.getBitmap())
  .signature(new ObjectKey(product.getId()))
  .into(holder.productImageView);
```

Assuming a Product with the same ID has been loaded before, then Glide should pull the image from the cache.

One further optimization here might be to calling `FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference()` when you know that the image will be coming from the cache. To do this, you could try loading using something similar to above, but set a listener and rely on the execution of `onLoadFailed()` to trigger the Firebase code before reattempting to load the image.